# WooCommerce product short descriptions on a Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I use WooCommerce shortcode to show some products on the front page.
Like this `[products limit="3" category="my-category" ids="86, 71, 54"]`.
The front page is a regular WordPress static page. The problem is that it doesn't show product short descriptions. If I use the code below but for is_front_page(), it shows short description of a regular WordPress post (not of the listed products).

```
function custom_short_description() {
if ( is_product_category() ) {
    echo '<div class="custom-short-description">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
} }

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_short_description', 45 );
```

Adding to the function

```
global $post;
$product = get_product($loop->post);
```

and using

```
$product->post->post_excerpt;
```

didn't help.
Any ideas how to show product short descriptions?

===================
Update
===================
If you create custom loops, you might want to create variables at the beginning of the loop and then use them:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $loop->post->ID );
$product_short_description = $product->get_short_description();
$product_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_short_description', 45 );

function custom_short_description() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
    global $product;

    echo '<div class="custom-short-description">' . $product->get_short_description() . '</div>';
    } 
}
```

This should get you the outcome you're looking for.

Tried and tested WordPress 5.1.

Comment: This works. Have found out the source. The problem is that I am using ACF, and in some places because of wp_reset_postdata() it loses $product.